# Apache POI Formula Evaluator not getting new result after setting new formula

Tags: excel, apache-poi, evaluation

I have an excel file that has formulas in some cells and some input fields based on which value is being computed in the Formula Cell.
step1

```
Double oldEvaluate = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell).getNumberValue();
```

to get the old value base on old formul.
step2

```
cell.setCellFormula(newFormula);
```

to set a new formula.
step3

```
Double  afterEvaluate = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell).getNumberValue();
```

all I want is to compare the afterEvaluate and oldEvaluate to see them are same or not，but I found afterEvaluate is always same as the oldEvaluate
Is there any way to get new value of the cell base on new formula I set at step2？

Is there any way to get new value of the cell base on new formula I set at step2？

Comment: Try https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#clearAllCachedResultValues-- or https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#notifyUpdateCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell- ?

Comment: #clearAllCachedResultValues works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Apache POI formula evaluator caches values, to speed up performance

If you make changes to the Workbook after creating a `FormulaEvaluator`, you have a few choices to have the changes noticed:

- Create a fresh `FormulaEvaluator` (slow)
- Call [clearAllCachedResultValues](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#clearAllCachedResultValues--) (nearly as slow)
- Tell the evaluator which cells you changed with [notifyUpdatedCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#notifyUpdateCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-) (fastest)